# Active Admin not works, SASS error can't convert Sass::Rails::Importer into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, activeadmin, freebsd

I install and configure "Active Admin" to my rails app. It works fine on two of my computers, but not work at my production server. I have this error both in production and development (FreeBSD server):

```
Started GET "/admin/login" for 192.168.0.1 at Wed Oct 26 22:12:53 +0300 2011


Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.4.9/app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb (2.2ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activeadmin-0.3.2/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (44.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 169ms

ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Sass::Rails::Importer into String
  (in /usr/home/url.od.ua/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)):
    6:   <title><%= [@page_title, active_admin_application.site_title].compact.join(" | ") %></title>
    7: 
    8:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.stylesheets.each do |path| %>
    9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag path %>
    10:   <% end %>
    11:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.each do |path| %>
    12:     <%= javascript_include_tag path %>
  app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss:1

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.6ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (10.4ms)
```

All gems installed! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Updating haml gem solved it:

```
gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.3'
```